# Figure moves downwards

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm using the below script to display a figure (long one which fits a whole page) and for a reason (I don't know) it moves downwards in below the text when the text finishes.So briefly I reference my pic (below) before a couple of paragraphs (which has couple of small figures), but for some reason this pics shifts to the end of the paragraphs and then all the other small pics comes after it, so it ends up like a couple of text paragraphs then figures below each other, and this is not what it should be. If anyone could please advise.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{fc.png}\caption{caption.}
\label{fc}
\end{figure}
```

This is my Pic:

[image]

Comment: I want a picture of your problem ...

Comment: @juanuni I don't know how to make a picture of problem because its in a couple of pages. But breifly I reference my pic before a couple of paragraphs (which has couple of small figures), but for some reason this pics shifts to the end of the paragraphs and then all the other small pics comes after it, so it ends up like a couple of text paragraphs then figures below each other, and this is not what it should be.

Comment: Ok, is possible problem with picture lengths, you need adjust that ...

Comment: And that pic is no necessary :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would appear that the `figure` is supposed to take up much, or even all, of a full page. If this impression is correct, you could use the `p` ("page") positioning specifier to direct LaTeX to place the float on a page by itself.

For good measure, I would also specify the (maximum) height of the graphic to be `0.95\textheight` or `0.9\textheight`, rather than simply `\textheight`, because the total height of the float comprises both the height of the graphic as well as that of the caption material.